# Its there a better way to execute this If statement code so it work faster?

Tags: vba, excel

As a new apprentice of VBA code, I have developed the following code which works on a spreadsheet to update data in the Col(17), update the priority in Col(13) and place a character in Col(14) depending on the update, the data is populated from Col(2) through to Col(19). It there any possible way to make this code better and faster.
Thanks very much.

CODE:

```
Sub StatusUpdate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim Rng As Range

Set ws = Sheet1
Set Rng = ws.Range("b10", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Rows)
For Each c In Rng
    days = c.Offset(0, 6) - Date
    'if activity is complete
    If c.Offset(0, 16) = 1 Then
      c.Offset(0, 15) = "Closed"
    'If activity is canceled
    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 15) = "Canceled" Then
        c.Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25AC)
    'activity is in hold
    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 15) = "Hold" Then
        c.Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H221E)
    'if the area is in hold and finish date is less than 14 dias
    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 15) = "Hold" And days < 14 Then
        c.Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H221E)
        c.Offset(0, 13) = "High"

    'if final date passed and activity is not completed
    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 16) < 1 And c.Offset(0, 6) < Date And c.Offset(0, 15) <> "Canceled" Then
        c.Offset(0, 15) = "Behind"
        c.Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25BC)
        c.Offset(0, 13) = "Critical"
    'if activity is less than 85% and only only remains 7 days in calendar
    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 6) > Date And days <= 7 And c.Offset(0, 16) < 0.85 And c.Offset(0, 15) <> "Canceled" Then
        c.Offset(0, 15) = "At risk"
        c.Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&HA4)
        c.Offset(0, 13) = "High"
    'if activiy is in progress and final date is not overdue
     ElseIf c.Offset(0, 6) > Date And c.Offset(0, 16) > 0 And c.Offset(0, 15) <> "Canceled" And c.Offset(0, 15) <> "Hold" Then
        c.Offset(0, 15) = "In progress"
        c.Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25B2)

    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 6) > Date And days > 7 And c.Offset(0, 3) > 0 Then
        c.Offset(0, 15) = "Open"
        c.Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25D9)
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Question asking how to optimize(speed up) working code belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's almost nothing at CodeReview for VBA - while I understand the intent it seems like an artificial divide: seems like we should be open to helping with "best practices" right here...

Comment: But the main answer you are going to get is to load the range into an array and cycle and test that loading an output array. Then when done assign the output array to the desired range.

Comment: What's wrong with that as an answer?  Sure it's a common solution, but most of the questions here are based on a pretty small set of common and recurring issues.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am more than willing to give pointers, but to truly do an optimization would require a full rewrite, and that, in my opinion, is too broad for this site and is why CodeReview exists.  Just like there are questions that are better suited for SuperUser, though most here can answer.  The question should go where it should.  At least that is my opinion.  But compared to you I am still a relative newbie.

Comment: My apologies if I have posted my question on the wrong website, I was looking for some help on how to improve my knowledge, but perhaps I came to the wrong place then

Comment: See [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/23788) if you want to understand when to ask on SO vs when to ask on CR. Shortly put: working code goes to CR, buggy code goes to SO.

Comment: @ScottCraner - to me it's the same amount of work wherever it is. If someone is willing to do it (and I sometimes am) then I don't much care if it's here over "over there".  I feel like it's helpful to less-experienced coders to be exposed to this type of thing while they may be looking for other answers.  I don't (didn't) really want to start a big debate though - horses for courses etc.

Comment: @TimWilliams No hard feelings on my side.  I enjoy a debate, sometimes too much.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

- the `Select Case` structure (more for readability purposes)
- eliminating some unuseful checks (being logical consequences of previous ones)
- `With ... End With` blocks, to avoid multiple referencing to the same objects

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub StatusUpdate()
      Dim c As Range
      Dim Days As Variant

      With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'reference your sheet
          For Each c In .Range("B10", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) 'loop through referenced sheet column B cells from row 10 down to last not empty one
              With c 'reference current cell
                  Days = .Offset(0, 6) - Date
                  Select Case True
                      'if activity is complete
                      Case .Offset(0, 16) = 1
                          .Offset(0, 15) = "Closed"

                      'If activity is canceled
                      Case .Offset(0, 15) = "Canceled"
                          .Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25AC)

                      'activity is in hold
                      Case .Offset(0, 15) = "Hold"
                          .Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H221E)
                          If Days < 14 Then .Offset(0, 13) = "High" 'if finish date is less than 14 dias

                      'if final date passed
                      Case .Offset(0, 6) < Date
                          If .Offset(0, 16) < 1 Then 'and  if activity is not completed
                              .Offset(0, 15) = "Behind"
                              .Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25BC)
                              .Offset(0, 13) = "Critical"
                          End If

                      'if final date is not overdue
                      Case .Offset(0, 6) > Date
                          Select Case True
                              'if activity is less than 85% and only only remains 7 days in calendar
                              Case Days <= 7 And .Offset(0, 16) < 0.85
                                  .Offset(0, 15) = "At risk"
                                  .Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&HA4)
                                  .Offset(0, 13) = "High"

                              'if activity is in progress
                              Case .Offset(0, 16) > 0
                                  .Offset(0, 15) = "In progress"
                                  .Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25B2)

                              Case Days > 7 And .Offset(0, 3) > 0
                                  .Offset(0, 15) = "Open"
                                  .Offset(0, 14) = ChrW(&H25D9)
                      End Select
                  End Select
              End With
          Next
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Code review.

Your big time driver is the loop through the range, On the surface, this seems fine - a single loop through without inner loops.

I would not use `c As Range` for your loop. You have already defined a range, you can now iterate from `1 to .Rows.Count` to get your data (`.Cells(iterator,<colno>)`) because you have a strong structure to your data. This would avoid using another complex object to do a simple job you are already set up to do.

I would also do an analysis on the complex `If` structure. Sometimes nested `if`s are easier to read and maintain. Sometimes you can gain small efficiencies by looking at how that is parsed. But this would be small gains compared to managing loops effectively.